# Change Google Chart positioning

Tags: google-visualization

When I use Google Charts it uses a position: absolute inside one of it's div's. That messes up the layout.

On the HTML I put:

```
<div id="chart-1-year" />
```

And the Javascript:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'Performance'],
    <%= CurrentData.first.chart_1_year%>
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart-1-year')).
      draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                  width: 500, height: 400, title: "Performance 1 Year"
                  }
          );
}
```

I get the following on the browser (using Firebug):

```
<div class="row">
<div id="chart-1-year" style="position: relative;">
<div style="position: relative; width: 500px; height: 400px;" dir="ltr">
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</div>
<div style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 410px; left: 510px; white-space: nowrap; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px;">Performance</div>
</div>
</div>
```

It works fine if I remove the "position: absolute;" from the inner div.

How can I change that position setting?

Comment: Can't you just create an "OnLoad" event that will use javascript to change the position? Something like `document.getElementById('chart-1-year').position='fixed';`?

Comment: It changes the outer div, the inner one still has the absolute position.

Comment: Can you try `document.getElementById('chart-1-year').div.position='fixed';` (setting the position for the div inside the chart-1-year div)?